# good laser scanner/ lidar for 4 wheel robot?

Tags: mobile-robot, lidar, laser, hardware

i was wondering what could be a good laser scanner can someone get for as much as 180$ ? i am planning to use it from SLAM to build a map, so this is why i wanted to ask here ? have anyone tried something that gives a good result?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* alarifmo, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to buy a cheap, second-hand, [Neato Robotics XV-15](https://www.neatorobotics.com/robot-vacuum/xv/xv-15/) robot vacuum-cleaner and use the LIDAR from that (you may even be able to buy the LIDAR unit separately).

[image: Lidar]

A lot of guides to using the Neato LIDAR for robots have been published. For example this one from Hackaday describes how to use the [Neato LIDAR with the Raspberry Pi](https://hackaday.com/2016/01/22/how-to-use-lidar-with-the-raspberry-pi/).

Just type [Neato Lidar robot](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=mx0kWtTINIa9gAaG1r3IAQ&q=Neato%20Lidar%20robot&oq=Neato%20Lidar%20robot&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i8i30k1l2.36175.36175.0.36963.1.1.0.0.0.0.66.66.1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.66....0.JAevagIs59M) into Google for more (this will also get you lots more useful background information about the LIDAR sensor itself, which is a bonus).

Comment: Thanks man, i found that it cost about 110 dollar, which is ok. There is also a very good scanner called rplidar A1, it about 150 dollar and from what i heard it is very easy to use, and it gives very good result.

Comment: @alarifmo I've managed to find second-hand units for about £30-50 here in the UK.